# Height transition not working using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to collapse a DIV using transition, only it is not working and I do not know how to get it it working using javascript.  The div collapses but instantly, rather than over 2 seconds as I would like when i press a designated button.  I am using chrome.

CSS for the div:

```
 .new_dynDiv {
text-align: left;
background-color: white;
padding: 5px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
```

}

my Javascript for collapsing the div using transition when a button is pressed:

```
 var div_article = document.getElementById('new_dynDiv_'+id);
                                div_article.style.height = '0px';
                                div_article.style.transition= 'height 2s';
```

I have also tried tried the following and still the transition has not worked:

```
 .new_dynDiv_fade{
height: 0px;
transition: height 2s;
```

}

javascript code for the above transition:

```
 var div_article = document.getElementById('new_dynDiv_'+id);
div_article.className = 'new_dynDiv_fade';
```

Comment: By the time you set the transition the height of the element is already changed. Why don't you add the transition to the `new_dynDiv` class instead defined in CSS?

Comment: i am sorry, i do not quite understand but would like to.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two options to achieve what you want:

- Use CSS animations
- Use jQuery animations

I've created a simple example with CSS animations. Hope it helps you.

```
<style>
    .new_dynDiv {
        text-align: left;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;

        height: 100px; /* the initial height needed for the animation to work*/
        transition: height 2s; /* the animation for the height property */
        overflow: hidden; /* hide the content of the element when collapsed */
    }

    .new_dynDiv.collapsed {
        height: 0px;
    }
</style>

<div class="new_dynDiv" id="new_dynDiv_1">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<button id="btnCollapse" onclick="toggleCollapsed(1); return false;">Collapse</button>

<script>
    function toggleCollapsed(id) {
        var div_article = document.getElementById('new_dynDiv_' + id);
        div_article.classList.toggle("collapsed");
    }
</script>
```